# Mechanisms and Assumptions of the Species-Area Realtionship

Tags: ecology, theoretical-biology, landscape-ecology

I would like to choose a model to use to describe a [species area relationship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Species-area_curve) based on plant species richness data that I have collected.  Rather than choosing the power model a priori, I am considering all options (eg. exponential, untransformed, etc).

Does anyone know of any good recent synthesis work on how to choose the best model?  Of particular interest are the assumptions behind each model, and the ecological mechanisms that each model might imply.

Comment: Disclaimer: I am NOT an ecologist! What do you mean species-area relationship? Do you mean number of species, or presence/absence of a particular species. I don't understand what the "species" variable is.

Comment: @Remi.b It's referring to the relationship between the species richness of a particular region/site and the area of that site. Such plots often follow a power function (i.e. linear on the log-log scale)

Answer (score 3):

[Dengler 2009](http://www.biodiversity-plants.de/downloads/JD125.pdf) would be a good start.

[image: Dengeler 2009]

I'm sure this paper, his citations and papers citing Dengler's paper will get you well on your way.